# How can I send a hex number and later do the necessary processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Python 3.6.8 and the Eclipse IDE. I'm trying to rearrange the hex value. My code snippet is as follows:

```py
def RearrangeData(Data, dataType):
    Data= Data[6:] + Data[4:6] + Data[2:4] + Data[0:2]
    return data
```

I'm calling this function as

```py
#xxxxxxxx is a jumbled hex value and it is of type Float
RearrangeData(xxxxxxxx, Float)
```

In 3.6.8, the interpreter takes the input as int and not as a string. How can this be fixed? Using what attribute can I decode a hex value for example(0x3F800000) to its IEEE-754 equivalent value? In Python 2.7.5, I could use RearragedData.decode('hex'). What can I use in Python 3.6.8?

Comment: Can you give an example of your function input?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotation marks around `xxxxxxx` (because otherwise if it contains only digits it __is__ an int) so it looks like `’xxxxxxx’`? And yes show us an actual value and then the __full__ error message you get.

Comment: @jmkjaer I would call my function like RearrangeData(6666A63F, 'Float'). The actual value of the hex is 1.3 in decimal

Comment: @barny That takes the number as a string, and later in my program i'm checking if that value is greater than 0x7F800001. When I do that, I get an error saying string and int cannot be compared. In Python 2.7.5, I could check if it was greater than 0x7F800001 and then use that data to decode into a decimal number. Now if I use quotes, I get an error saying that string has no attribute decode. What is the attribute decode in Python 3.6.8?

Comment: Using what attribute can I decode 0x3FA66666 to its equivalent IEEE-754 value?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string with hexadecimal digits representing a floating point number in big-endian format, use a combination of `struct` and `codecs` to first unhexlify the hex string to binary, then unpack it into a float.

```
>>> import struct, codecs
>>> struct.unpack('>f', codecs.decode('3FA66666', 'hex'))
(1.2999999523162842,)
```

If you have an integer, `0x3FA66666` (i.e. 1067869798 in decimal), you can call `hex()` on it, strip the `0x` prefix and do the above:

```
>>> v = 0x3FA66666
1067869798
>>> v_hex = hex(v)[2:]
'3fa66666'
>>> struct.unpack('>f', codecs.decode(v_hex, 'hex'))
(1.2999999523162842,)
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error saying, NameError: name 'codecs' is not defined

Comment: You will need to, of course, import the modules. Added that as an edit.

Comment: How do I compare the hexstring with a hex value? For example, I want to check if the hexstring I give is greater than 0x3F800000. When I try to achieve this, an error occurs saying int and string cannot be comapred

Comment: If you're looking to compare them as integers, you can use `int(hex_string, 16)` to convert the hex string to an integer.